# How to find the real class name from obfuscated ProGuard classname in my source code?

Tags: proguard, deobfuscation, android-security, trustmanager

I got an email from Google about [unsafe implementation of TrustManager](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016?hl=en)
with the only clue that the problematic code is in com.b.a.af class. Clearly that's the obfuscated name. How would I get the real class name from that obfuscated class name, in my own source code. Is there any way to lookup the mapping that ProGuard does? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the mappings each class should look like this:

```
me.vader.event.EventMouseClick -> f:
    int buttonID -> q
    boolean mouseDown -> r
    void <init>() -> <init>
    void fire(int,boolean) -> a
    int getButtonID() -> n
```

You can see the obvious before -> after convention. So finding the original names should be really easy.

Comment: I am getting 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Abstract class can't be instantiated! Class name: e.c.a.l.k0 How to find classname and where?